# Map component only showing properly when reloading

Tags: reactjs, openlayers

Im starting with React and I have this component for a map in openlayers that just returns the div with the map. This apparently works fine when it loads the Map page from the beginning. But when you navigate to this page from any other of the site it just doesn't load the map (it will if you click reload while on this Map page). Below is the code for the map component.

I've tried something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/43p10r6w94) but it won't work since the libraries are different and a lot more problems. And [this](https://taylor.callsen.me/using-reactflux-with-openlayers-3-and-other-third-party-libraries/) is from where I built my code.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

var ol = require('openlayers')
require('openlayers/css/ol.css')

class Map extends Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        var map = new ol.Map({
            target: this.refs.map,
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                  source: new ol.source.Stamen({
                      layer: 'toner'
                  })
                })
            ],
            view: new ol.View({
                center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-4.42, 36.71]),
                zoom: 13,
            })
        })

        this.setState({
            map: map,
        })
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div id='map' ref='map'></div>
        )
    }
}

export default Map
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Turns out this was a problem with `flex`. The openlayers container was inside a `div` that had `display: flex`, `flex: 1` and `min-width: 0` so when the sidebar menu came and **took the whole screen** (this is important because if the width of the element doesn't go to zero the map adjusts perfectly to the new size), the content width was adjusted to 0, as the sidebar menu gave way and the content loaded it loaded from width 0 wich behaved fine for the text but not for the map.

```
<div className='content-wrapper'>
    <div className='another-div'>
        <div className='map'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SOLUTION:**

Set flex of the content to 0 and width to 100vw. So when the sidebar menu is opened the content just slides out of the screen without resizing.